# Event behind a dialog material angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is my first post here, I have a little question. I would like to do some event when I opened my dialog with angular material. I can't because my parent is locked until I don't close my dialog.
To resume:
I create a dialog window from my button and I would like to be able to continue to write on my parent page when my dialog window is open.

[image: clipboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set the `hasBackdrop: false` in the config. For instance, by lack of code on your hand, you should do something like this:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog, {
  hasBackdrop: false
});
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qohbkt?file=src/app/dialog-content-example.ts)

You can see that you are still able to click the 'Open dialog' button.

If you also want to prevent closing by clicking on 'escape', you should add the `disableClose: true` option to the config as well